# Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus Share

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to share/like a link on facebook,twitter and google plus using phone gap

Can anyone suggest best practice to implement it?

I have goes through Share this plugin for html5, is it good for phone gap as my site build on Phone gap + jquery Mobile ?

I like to make it simple, if i can get this thing done using HTML5 and css then i dont want to go for Phone gap + facebook plugin and all stuffs

And if anything regarding this topic is really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through the same issue. There's a plugin to share links or text on social network sites. This socialshare plugin is available on github link https://github.com/mayurloved/Share-Plugin-for-iPhone-and-Android & https://github.com/mayurloved/socialshare-windows.

It helped me. I hope it helps you out. good luck! :)